# Why doesn't Python3 sort dictionary keys?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
dictionary = {'key5':10, 'key2':20}
dictionary["key3"] = 21
dictionary["key1"] = 22
dictionary["key2"] = 23

sorted(dictionary.keys())
for key,value in dictionary.items():
  print(key)
```

After sorting and printing, the values look like this:

```
key5 
key1 
key2 
key3
```

Why isn't "key5" last?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because `sorted(dictionary.keys())` actually [gives you a list](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted) of sorted keys, it *doesn't* modify the collection itself so that the keys will come out sorted. From that link (my bold):

> Return a **new** sorted list from the items in *iterable.*

You're calling `sorted` to get the sorted list of keys but then you're basically throwing it away and going back to the *unsorted* collection with `dictionary.items()`.

To process the keys in order, you need something like:

```
for key in sorted(dictionary.keys()):
    print(key)
```

This will print out, as desired:

```
key1
key2
key3
key5
```

Answer (score 2):

`sorted()` returns the sorted sequence. You need to iterate over this sequence in order to get sorted results.